# Unit testing for method using database bounded when application started

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing, nunit

I use NUnit for my unit-testing. In my current project, I have a problem in which almost all of the functions I want to test are connected to the database. Meanwhile, the database is bounded when the application is started.

I am so confused now, I have read regarding mock unit-testing, but don't know exactly how to handle this problem. Any solution for me here?

To make things harder, this database is static, not as parameter of my method... This makes me so confused

Comment: you need to mock database access statements using a mocking framework. You can use moles framework. refer to: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/

Comment: @daryal: how exactly? Let's say I have a method X(), this method accesses static database DB which is initialized when my application started. Now what can I do to mock this DB?

Comment: moles allows you to even mock framework functions. More information and code is needed to provide a proper answer...

Comment: @daryal: okay. I use MVC3 here, my database is initialized when doing Application_Start on Global.asax.cs. I have a method that inits DbContext (that accessing this database) and the DbContext is static. Now, how to test this method?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to review the architecture of your application. Make sure the database layer is loosely coupled, for example by using interfaces. This will make it possible to write stubs or mocks for your database layer.

Comment: I have already created classes to map the database, however I still have no idea...

Answer (score 1):

The normal solution to this is to keep your data layer in a separate class that implements a well-known interface. For instance:

```
public interface IDataLayer
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers();

    Order GetOrderById(int id);
}
```

You will implement the interface as normal for your actual data access

```
public class SqlServerDataLayer : IDataLayer
{
    // implementation
}
```

But in your tests, you can now use a mocking framework like Moq or RhinoMocks to set up a mock data layer that returns test data. This ensures you are only testing how your classes use the data, which is ideal.

```
[Test]
public void TestGettingCustomersRefreshesViewModel()
{
    //arrange
    var mockDb = new Mock<IDataLayer>();
    mockDb.Setup(db => db.GetAllCustomers()).Returns(new List<Customer>());
    underTest.DataRepository = mockDb.Object;

    //act
    underTest.GetCustomerCommand.Execute();

    //assert
    Assert.That(underTest.CustomerList != null);
}
```

Comment: what kind of mock UT did you use here?

Comment: I used Moq here. I like it - it's clean and functional and very readable, once you get past the lambdas.